# react app resets state and rerenders without e.preventDefault on click

Tags: reactjs, typescript, event-handling, preventdefault

I have a react app that seems to be resetting all of its state and re-renders the entire app when button is clicked:

the form + button:

```
<form>
...
    <button
      onClick={(e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
        // e.preventDefault()
      }}>
    </button>
</form>
```

calling `preventDefault()` fixes the problem which suggests to me that the event is bubbling up the DOM tree and triggering other handlers, but there aren't any handlers that should be causing a refresh-like phenomenon like this.

As per Igor Gonak's suggestion, it also stops happening when I change the enclosing `<form>` element to a `<div>`.

However, it only occurs the first time on a fresh tab after running `npm start` and I have to close the tab and restart the development build to reproduce the issue.

Any ideas what could be going on? or has anyone encountered similar problems before?

Comment: What is the context of your button? Is it for example inside a form? Then it automatically gets type=submit. Please show more code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @IgorGonak you're right, it seems related to form behavior but only occurs on fresh build/load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per Igor Gonak's comment, the issue was caused by button type defaulting to `submit`. In this particular case it was resolved by specifying `type='button'` on the button.

Comment: Please mark your answer as solved